# Tools to Visualize Project Growth

Tags: git, svn, version-control, visualization

I've got a couple of projects in Git and SVN that I'd like to visualize the growth of over time.  Maybe not just lines of code, but also who committed what (deletions and insertions for this would be great).

Are there any readily available tools that will let me do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gource](http://gource.io/) can visualize developing process of Git, Mercurial and SVN repositories.